# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal and Vertical Divider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble to put in horizontal and vertical lines on my website. Not sure what's wrong with this.

I tried using borders but I am not sure if I am doing it right.

I would like to achieve a criss-cross dividers just like the below image:

[image]

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<div class="container-liquid" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan" id="one"><h5>Rich Media Ad Production</h5><img src="images/richmedia.png"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan" id="two"><h5>Web Design & Development</h5> <img src="images/web.png" ></div>               
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan" id="three"><h5>Mobile Apps Development</h5> <img src="images/mobile.png"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center rightspan" id="four"><h5>Creative Design</h5> <img src="images/mobile.png"> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><hr></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan" id="five"><h5>Web Analytics</h5> <img src="images/analytics.png"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan" id="six"><h5>Search Engine Marketing</h5> <img src="images/searchengine.png"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan" id="seven"><h5>Mobile Apps Development</h5> <img src="images/socialmedia.png"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center rightspan" id="eight"><h5>Quality Assurance</h5> <img src="images/qa.png"></div>

        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you write any of your own css for this? And if so can we see it?

Comment: I'm sure this post is outdated, but you should have given us a screenshot of how your current implementation looks as well as the html, css and list of any frameworks like bootstrap you have used. Just saying....

Answer (score 37):

Do you have to use Bootstrap for this? Here's a basic HTML/CSS example for obtaining this look that doesn't use any Bootstrap:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="box-content right">Rich Media Ad Production</div>
    <div class="box-content right">Web Design & Development</div>
    <div class="box-content right">Mobile Apps Development</div>
    <div class="box-content">Creative Design</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="box-content right">Web Analytics</div>
    <div class="box-content right">Search Engine Marketing</div>
    <div class="box-content right">Social Media</div>
    <div class="box-content">Quality Assurance</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box-content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.right {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Here is the [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SrPT/155/).

---

### UPDATE

If you must use Bootstrap, here is a semi-responsive example that achieves the same effect, although you may need to write a few additional media queries.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Rich Media Ad Production</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Web Design & Development</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Mobile Apps Development</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Creative Design</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Web Analytics</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Search Engine Marketing</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Social Media</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Quality Assurance</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.col-xs-3:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Here is another [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhaxpzLh/).

**Note:**

Note that you may also use the `<hr>` element to insert a horizontal divider in Bootstrap as well if you'd like.

Comment: Using `col-xs-6`-like classes in Bootstrap 3 gives you power of fluid / responsible layout, which adapts to device actual screen dimensions. This is pretty neat in Bootstrap 3 (and all others, that implements similar logic). Your "simple" code, while works, seems to not have this feature.

Comment: @trejder I've added a basic Bootstrap example.

Comment: An alternative to `.row:not(:last-child) { border-bottom: ...` is `.row + .row { border-top: ...` - essentially that puts a top border on all rows except the first one. I've seen that method in the Bootstrap source code.

Answer (score 17):

The `<hr>` should be placed inside a `<div>` for proper functioning.

Place it like this to get desired width
        `

```
<div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2'>
        <hr>
       </div>
       </div>
```

`

Hope this helps a future reader!

Comment: Thanks, what about vertical lines?

Answer (score 7):

Add the right lines this way and and the horizontal borders using HR or *border-bottom* or *.col-right-line:after*. Don't forget media queries to get rid of the lines on small devices.

```
.col-right-line:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: @color-neutral;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

*I know this is an "older" post. This question and the provided answers helped me get ideas for my own problem. I think this solution addresses the OP question (intersecting borders with 4 and 2 columns depending on display)*

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/tqmfpwhv/1/

---

**css** based on OP information, media query at end is for med & lg view.

```
.vr-all {
    padding:0px;
    border-right:1px solid #CC0000;
}
.vr-xs {
    padding:0px;
}
.vr-md {
    padding:0px;
}
.hrspacing { padding:0px; }
.hrcolor {
    border-color: #CC0000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
/* for medium and up */
@media(min-width:992px){
    .vr-xs {
        border-right:1px solid #CC0000;
    }
    }
```

**html** adjustments to OP provided code. Red border and Img links for example.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-all" id="one">
            <h5>Rich Media Ad Production</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-xs" id="two">
            <h5>Web Design & Development</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>

        <!-- hr for only x-small/small viewports -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg hrspacing"><hr class="hrcolor"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-all" id="three">
            <h5>Mobile Apps Development</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-md" id="four">
            <h5>Creative Design</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>

        <!-- hr for for all viewports -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 hrspacing"><hr class="hrcolor"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-all" id="five">
            <h5>Web Analytics</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-xs" id="six">
            <h5>Search Engine Marketing</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>

        <!-- hr for only x-small/small viewports -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg hrspacing"><hr class="hrcolor"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-all" id="seven">
            <h5>Mobile Apps Development</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center vr-md" id="eight">
            <h5>Quality Assurance</h5>
            <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/mobile_phone.png" >
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following little scss mixin to build for all the bootstrap breakpoints...

With it I get `.col-xs-divider-left` or `col-lg-divider-right` etc.

> **Note:** this uses v4-alpha bootstrap syntax...

```
@import 'variables';

$divider-height: 100%;

@mixin make-column-dividers($breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
    // Common properties for all breakpoints
    %col-divider {
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        top: (100% - $divider-height)/2;
        height: $divider-height;
        width: $hr-border-width;
        background-color: $hr-border-color;
    }
    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
        .col-#{$breakpoint}-divider-right:before {
            @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
                @extend %col-divider;
                right: 0;
            }
        }
        .col-#{$breakpoint}-divider-left:before {
            @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
                @extend %col-divider;
                left: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.vr {
   border-right: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 vr">
       <p>Column 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Column 2</p>
   </div>
</div
```

Now, we can use class `vr` wherever we need to have a *vertical-divider* kind of appearance.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by adding border class of bootstrap

like for border left ,you can use border-left

working code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan border-right border-bottom" id="one"><h5>Rich Media Ad Production</h5><img src="images/richmedia.png"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan border-right border-bottom" id="two"><h5>Web Design & Development</h5> <img src="images/web.png" ></div>               
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan border-right border-bottom" id="three"><h5>Mobile Apps Development</h5> <img src="images/mobile.png"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center rightspan  border-bottom" id="four"><h5>Creative Design</h5> <img src="images/mobile.png"> </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"><hr></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan border-right" id="five"><h5>Web Analytics</h5> <img src="images/analytics.png"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan border-right" id="six"><h5>Search Engine Marketing</h5> <img src="images/searchengine.png"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center leftspan border-right"  id="seven"><h5>Mobile Apps Development</h5> <img src="images/socialmedia.png"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center rightspan" id="eight"><h5>Quality Assurance</h5> <img src="images/qa.png"></div>

    <hr>
</div>
```

for more refrence al bootstrap classes
[all classes ,search for border](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp)