# How do you make a horizontal scroll bar using bootstrap's grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I'm trying to using bootstrap's columns and the combined total is 24.  Now I know after a combined total of 12 it breaks to a line, but is there a way to keep it on the same line and just use a horizontal scroll bar to view the rest? this is what I have in the view:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>Example</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="Description_cat_well">
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Example</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="Description_cat_well">
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Example</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="Description_cat_well">
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Example</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="Description_cat_well">
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Example</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="Description_cat_well">
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Example</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="Description_cat_well">
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Example</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is what I have in my less file:

```
  .well {
    height: 325px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 150%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.box{
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.row {
    width:150%;
 }
```

Surround your row with another div (box)

Comment: Sorry that didn't work.  It did make my wells inside of the `<div class="Description_cat_well">` bigger, so now only 2 are visible versus the 3,  but wouldn't allow me to scroll and see the rest

Comment: I forgot to mention that you had to remove the styling on your well.

Answer (score 0):

```
.well{
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

like that ?

And : [Bootstrap 3 Horizontal and Vertical Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343659/bootstrap-3-horizontal-and-vertical-divider)

EDIT:

You can at least have all your columns on the same line :

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>Example</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <div class="Description_cat_well">
                                    <div class="well">
                                        <h4>Example</h4>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <div class="Description_cat_well">
                                    <div class="well">
                                        <h4>Example</h4>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <div class="Description_cat_well">
                                    <div class="well">
                                        <h4>Example</h4>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="Description_cat_well">
                                <div class="well">
                                    <h4>Example</h4>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="Description_cat_well">
                                <div class="well">
                                   <h4>Example</h4>
                                   <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="Description_cat_well">
                                <div class="well">
                                    <h4>Example</h4>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here i add another "row" to split your screen in two (you don't have any scroll bar but it is on the same line).

you got :

```
<row>
  <slit in two>
    <row>
      <split in three>
      <split in three>
      <split in three>
    </row>
  </split in two>
  <slit in two>
    <row>
      <split in three>
      <split in three>
      <split in three>
    </row>
  </split in two>
</row>
```

I can't do much more...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no that's not even what I'm asking.  Border color has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: even after you edited your answer that still isn't what I'm talking about.  sure the dividers look nice, but that has nothing to do with what i asked. Please re-read the question, because that couldn't be stated any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  MrSangrief answer was close and practically on the money, but there is no need for an additional div. I figured I would give a for dummies (like myself haha) answer. You need to increase the row percentage.  Example:

```
.row {
  width: 200%;  
}
```

A `col-lg-1` will equal the exact size of a `col-lg-2` that has a normal row width of 100%.  And so on and so forth.  Regardless of the size a combined total of 12 and under will always be on one line.

Comment: I added the div so the <h3> stays in place when you scroll the Description_cat_well elements.

Comment: oh ok nvm.  Thank you.  I just ending using `position: absolute` for that but thank you